# Listar variables en un PDF

Tags: php, javascript, dompdf

Estoy haciendo un configurador donde el cliente va seleccionando sobre datos nativos de javascript y los voy exponiendo en un `div`.

Estos datos los estoy pasando por `AJAX` para convertirlos en variables de `php` y luego con `dompdf` los relleno con esas variables.

El problema que me encuentro que al mandar esto:

```
var complementosGenerales = [
      { "general": "Aislamiento 3cm", "precio2": 0 },
      { "general": "Aislamiento 5cm", "precio2": 0 },
      { "general": "Aislamiento 8cm", "precio2": 0 },
      { "general": "Paredes de Pladur", "precio2": 100 },
      { "general": "Paredes de Madera", "precio2": 100 },
      { "general": "Paredes de Vinilo", "precio2": 100 },
      { "general": "Suelo de Baldosa", "precio2": 100 },
      { "general": "Suelo de Parket", "precio2": 100 },
      { "general": "Suelo de PVC", "precio2": 100 },
      ];

function functionPonerGeneral(x,general){
    var elemento2 = complementosGenerales[ general ];
    $( "#generalElegido" ).append('<div id="General'+general+'" class="col-12 listado22" data-id="" data-precio="'+elemento2.precio2+'">'+elemento2.general+'<span class="pull-right">'+elemento2.precio2+',00 €</span></div>' );
    total += elemento2.precio2;
    mostrarTotal();
  }
```

**de la siguiente manera:**

```
'general': $("#generalElegido").html(),
```

Me manda el `div` completo y no puedo estructurar bien el PDF ya que lo hace todo en la misma linea.

**Entonces intente esto:**

```
$( "#generalElegido" ).append('<div id="General'+general+'" class="col-12 listado22" data-id="" data-precio="'+elemento2.precio2+'"><span id="productosGenerales">'+elemento2.general+'</span><span class="pull-right" id="preciosGenerales">'+elemento2.precio2+',00 €</span></div>' );
```

**Para concretar más puse esto:**

```
<span id="productosGenerales">'+elemento2.general+'</span> <!--Le añado un span y un ID para pasar solo el campo ese.-->

<span class="pull-right" id="preciosGenerales">'+elemento2.precio2+',00 €</span>  <!--Aquí hago lo mismo para llevarme el precio.-->
```

**Y me lo llevo del siguiente modo:**

```
  'productosGenerales': $("#productosGenerales").html(),
  'preciosGenerales': $("#preciosGenerales").html(),
```

Que sucede, que si elijo tres cosas solo me exporta el `post` la primera que elijo. Además luego tiene que ir distribuido así:

```
<tr class="border_bottom">
   <td style="color: #424141; font-weight: bold;padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;font-size: 10px;">Aquí el nombre del producto
   </td>
   <td align="right" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;font-size: 10px;">&nbsp;</d> 
   <td align="right" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;font-size: 10px;">Aquí el precio €</td>

   <td align="right" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;font-size: 10px;">1</td>
   <td align="right" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;font-size: 10px;">Aquí el precio €</td>
 </tr>
```

Además que tendría que ser un `foreach` para que saque todos los seleccionado, ya que puede ser uno o más.

No se como hacerlo alguna idea??

Comment: ¿No has pensado en mandar los datos de los elementos seleccionados para generar el PDF que deseas y no un html que puede o no tener el formato que quieres?

Comment: Pero @OscarGarcia pero es estilo factura, del modo que tu dices seria posible hacerlo así. Ilustrame un poco de como dices de hacerlo. Lo hice de la forma que se me paso por la cabeza, gracias!

Comment: Para empezar: ¿vas a emitir un PDF estilo factura con datos enviados por el cliente? Menos mal que no lo firmas digitalmente :) Estos datos deberían estar en tu base de datos, ¿me equivoco?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia por el momento no los he almacenado en la BD por que tengo el mimo problema

Comment: Tienes el mismo problema porque no estás abordando el problema de la manera correcta. Debes enviar al PHP sólo aquellos elementos que hayas agregado al carrito, en JSON por ejemplo, y con esa información generar el PDF. Aunque lo más lógico es primero tramitar el pedido, almacenarlo en base de datos, y luego procesarlo para generar el PDF.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, primero almacenarlo en la base de datos y después crear el documento y esa es la idea, pero no se como llevarme los datos de forma correcta, pensaba que así estaba bien, pero ya veo que no porque no puedo hacer lo que quiero de este modo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107681/discussion-between-miguel-and-oscargarcia).